# how to navigate between webview pages described in different files

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Good day, I have such a problem. The application is made on the basis of webview, at the beta stage. And I faced such a problem that after the registration stage I need to launch a separate page in which the native elements and the webview are combined. Please give a tip on how to cope with this task
U.P.D The crux of the problem is this. I have a file that describes one webview page. I need to make sure that after the user is registered, he is thrown to another file, where the webview is also described, but in addition to the webview there are native menu elements for the user to navigate the application. If it's not clear, I can try to make a block diagram, maybe this will be clearer

Comment: What you actually want to do? Please clear your question